# Implement a table of components for gatsby blog using intersection observer

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dom, gatsby

I have  implemented a table of contents component for my blog posts written in mdx. Now I want to highlight the link in ToC corresponding to the section of blog a user is reading.  Here is my approach:

Use Intersection Observer to observe the  sections corresponding to headings in my post and style the corresponding link in table of contents.

Now here is the problem I am facing. I don't know how to target the whole section  corresponding to a  heading in the generated html (For example the all the paragraphs between two H3s in the image). 
Please help me out. 
[image]

```
    const navLinkToHighlight = useRef(null);
    useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
        entries.forEach(entry => {
            const id = entry.target.getAttribute('id');
            const selector = `nav a[href="${fields.slug}#${id}"]`
            const className = 'Toc--link-active'

            if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
                if (navLinkToHighlight.current) {
                    navLinkToHighlight.current.classList.remove(className);
                    navLinkToHighlight.current = document.querySelector(selector);
                    navLinkToHighlight.current.classList.add(className);
                } else {
                    navLinkToHighlight.current = document.querySelector(selector);
                    navLinkToHighlight.current.classList.add(className);
                }
            }
            });
    });

        document.querySelectorAll('article a[id]').forEach(headingLink => {
            observer.observe(headingLink);
        });
    });
```

As you can see, I attempted to observe the section headings but it is of no use because as soon as the heading leaves the intersection bounds, I cannot determine which section I am on.